# Long running export to excel job in Aspnet Core 2.1 Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, azure-functions, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am having an angular 4 application with AspNetCore 2.1 Web Api on server side (for restful services). Application is hosted in Azure App service.
Application has a functionality of exporting a data in excel format. More than 100k rows are expected in the excel.Azure app service has a timeout limit of 3.8 minutes . If the request is going beyond 3.8 minutes, Azure load balancer will cancel the request and users often gets the error.
To resolve this issue, I have decided to move this task to background process and will provide updates to the user using SingalR till the time task is complete. Flow of the application will be following

1. User clicks on export to excel button.
2. AspNetCore API will handle this call and puts the request in a Azure topic.
3. Azure function will subscribe to the Azure topic, once it receives notification it will start processing data. It will fetch the data from Azure SQL.
4. Azure function will periodically talk to SignalR hub about the progress of task. SignalR hub will push notification to the client. Client will receive this notification and user will be aware about the progress of task.
5. Once the data is ready, Azure function will prepare excel and send it to SignalR hub. SignalR hub will push this file to the client.

I am not sure whether this is right approach. As per [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-best-practices), one should avoid long running functions.
Also I read SignalR should be avoided to push the files.

is there any better solutions to achieve the functionality i.e. export the data to excel in background process and push it to client once it is ready

Answer (score 2):

Usually in these kind of scenario, we offer customer near real time solution.
What you could do to resolve this issue:

1) Give a button click to export user data ( excel file with 100K rows or more).

2) Notify user , that user request for export is submitted.

3) Also add a refresh button functionality which will get the status of file export.

4) Have a web job behind the scene which will process your file and upload the processed file in azure storage, maybe in a blob.

5) Once the blob file is available , Update the status to completed.

6) Provide a link enabled option to download file which will be an endpoint url of your blob.

In that way you main thread won't b locked and screen will be responsive too.

If you don't want to have Refresh Button functionality to keep checking the report.You could utilize signalR to keep the connection alive and set a timeed option to keep checking your blob file. Once the file is available in the blob, simply update the label.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

> export the data to excel in background process and push it to client once it is ready

You could try to use [azure webjob to run in background and continuously](https://sandervandevelde.wordpress.com/2016/07/19/turning-a-console-app-into-a-long-running-azure-webjob/) or use [Azure Batch Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/background-jobs) so you could long run to export data to excel and store it in Storage blob.

When the website is running, the associated jobs are running. And you could use a queueTrigger or httpTrigger in webjob, and call webjob from website. In general, we have to force the Azure website to be **always on**. Go to the Azure website application settings and turn on the `Always On`.

And as you have pointed out: **SignalR is for real time messaging not uploading files**. So you could use [WebClient.UploadFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfile?view=netframework-4.7.2) method to upload file to client.